# how to redirect page after 5 seconds on submission

Tags: database, redirect

I need to redirect the page after submission. In which the login details fails means it need to show the error message and redirect to login form. Kindly suggest the path is below in controller i done

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
    //Here code for other process
}

header('Refresh: 5;url='.$this->index);
```

i also try:

```
header('Refresh: 5;url=login.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Function to load specified or default URL.
function load( $page = 'login.php' )
{
  # Begin URL with protocol, domain, and current directory.
  $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . dirname( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

  # Remove trailing slashes then append page name to URL.
  $url = rtrim( $url, '/\\' ) ;
  $url .= '/' . $page ;

  # Execute redirect then quit. 
  header( "Location: $url" ) ; 
  exit() ;
}
```

Use like so:

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] = $data[ 'user_id' ] ;

  #calling redirect function
  load ( 'home.php' ) ;
```